# Is it ok to use circular references in the profile url?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

In order to get the autobiographer badge, quite a few SO users put the URL of the SO profile as their URL. Is this ok, or should this be disallowed?

Comment: OMG, WE WILL ALL DIE!

Comment: What other URL do I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tons of people do this, I don't see a problem with it.  They can put whatever they want in their profile.  If they don't want to put a personal site in their profile, so be it.  Autobiographer is one of the trivial badges, no need to put big stipulations on it.

Answer (score 2):

They could put a space, save, and then delete it again immediately after getting the badge. Autobiographer is on the bottom of the list of badges we should worry about people getting unfairly

---

Come to think of it, I don't have that badge; I'm going to put a link to this post in my profile to get it :)